# Formatting string in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, string, string-formatting

I want to do something similar to this in C language:

```
# This example is in Python language

var1 = 10
var2 = 45
var3 = 76

text = "Numbers are: %d, %d, %d." % (var1, var2, var3)
```

Is this possible in C? I want to say a solution for pure C, not C++.

## EDIT:

I don't want to print the string directly, I only want to storage formatted string.

Comment: read about `array` in C. [in this case, only `int`s]

Comment: Printing variables is such a basic function, it simply *must* have been covered in even the most abridged courses. This suggests you should consider starting again in your teaching book from the very first chapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html)

```
int var1 = 10;
int var2 = 45;
int var3 = 76;
char text[100];

snprintf(text, sizeof text, "Numbers are: %d, %d, %d.", var1, var2, var3);
```

Comment: In this simple case you are safe enough, but in general you should check the return of `snprintf()` to see if everything fit.  `int n; n = snprintf(text, sizeof(text), ...); if (n >= sizeof(text)) { /*ohcrap*/}`

Comment: With well controlled `printf()`-ing, code can use a right-sized buffer. `const char format [] = "Numbers are: %d, %d, %d."; char text[sizeof format + 3 * (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BITS/3 + 3)]; sprintf(text, format, var1, var2, var3);`.

Comment: @chux, `snprintf()` can return the exact number of bytes needed. `n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "Numbers are: %d, %d, %d.", var1, var2, var3); text = malloc(n + 1) /* I don't like VLAs; but your usage is ok */; snprintf(text, n + 1, "Numbers are: %d, %d, %d.", var1, var2, var3);`

Comment: Agreed that `snprintf()` can return the exact number of bytes needed, but then 2 calls are needed.  As with many coding tasks, there are a number of good approaches. Note, my comment does not use a VLA but a fixed sized buffer like your accepted answer.

Comment: You're right about the VLA. I wasn't paying enough attention. I apologize.

Answer (score 3):

Closest implementation would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char text[100];
    int var1 = 10;
    int var2 = 45;
    int var3 = 76;
    sprintf(text, "Numbers are : %d, %d, %d", var1, var2, var3);
}
```

Comment: This _would_ be the best answer, but you did your curly braces wrong... :P

Comment: You forgot `return 0;`

Comment: @thohl Sorry, still beginner here :)

Comment: @CoolGuy Actually, I didn't. I skip stuff when there's no harm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible in C

```
int main()
{
int var1,var2,var3;
var1 = 10;
var2 = 45;
var3 = 76;
printf("Numbers are: %d %d %d", var1, var2, var3);
return 0;
}
```

Writes the C string pointed by format to the standard output (stdout). If format includes format specifiers (subsequences beginning with %), the additional arguments following format are formatted and inserted in the resulting string replacing their respective specifiers.
For more details about printf() you can visit the link below: 
refer : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ it's same for C also